# Javascript loop skipping iterations

Tags: javascript

I am working in a javascript function that takes all of the id's from a HTML table and sends each iteration of a loop and sends the info to a PLSQL procedure to update. I concat a number on each id to make each one unique. If I add an alert in the loop and click through one by one it works. If I let it go on its own with no alert it skips some iterations. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

```js
function process_update() {
  var nDataCount = document.getElementById("v_nDataCount").value;
  var p_cc_no = document.getElementById("p_cc_no").value;
  var p_orient = document.getElementById("p_orient").value;
  var p_ot = document.getElementById("p_ot").value;
  var p_buy = document.getElementById("p_buy").value;
  var x = 0;

  if (nDataCount == 0) {
    x = 0;
  } else {
    x = 1;
  }

  for (i = nDataCount; i >= x; i--) {
    var p_pc_no = ("p_pc_no[" + i + "]");
    var p_pc_no2 = document.getElementById(p_pc_no).value;

    var p_tm_name = ("p_tm_name[" + i + "]");
    var p_tm_name2 = document.getElementById(p_tm_name).value;

    var p_tm_no = ("p_tm_no[" + i + "]");
    var p_tm_no2 = document.getElementById("p_tm_no").value;

    var p_status = ("p_status[" + i + "]");
    var p_status2 = document.getElementById(p_status).value;

    var p_hrs_per_week = ("p_hrs_per_week[" + i + "]");
    var p_hrs_per_week2 = document.getElementById(p_hrs_per_week).value;

    var p_shift = ("p_shift[" + i + "]");
    var p_shift2 = document.getElementById(p_shift).value;

    var p_open = ("p_open[" + i + "]");
    var p_open2 = document.getElementById(p_open).value;

    var p_vacant = ("p_vacant[" + i + "]");
    var p_vacant2 = document.getElementById(p_vacant).value;

    var p_comments = ("p_comments[" + i + "]");
    var p_comments2 = document.getElementById(p_comments).value;

    var p_delete = ("p_delete[" + i + "]");
    var p_delete2 = document.getElementById(p_delete).value;

    window.location.href = "https://server.server.com/db/schema.package.p_process2?p_cc_no=" + p_cc_no + "&p_pc_no=" + p_pc_no2 + "&p_tm_name=" + p_tm_name2 + "&p_tm_no=" + p_tm_no2 + "&p_status=" + p_status2 + "&p_hrs_per_week=" + p_hrs_per_week2 + "&p_shift=" + p_shift2 + "&p_open=" + p_open2 + "&p_vacant=" + p_vacant2 + "&p_comments=" + p_comments2 + "&p_delete=" + p_delete2 + "&p_orient=" + p_orient + "&p_ot=" + p_ot + "&p_buy=" + p_buy + "";
  }
```

Comment: why are you changing `window.location.href` inside a for loop????

Comment: The code you have right now will redirect the browser at the end of each iteration of the loop... which makes no sense because it would just get redirected once after the first iteration, and then you would no long be on the page where this script is running.  I'd recommend re-thinking what you need to do here.  At the very least change `window.location.href = "https://..."` to `console.log("https://...")` so you can see all the results in the console at once.

Comment: Also, using GET with these many params is going to blow up someday. But to answer the question, changing HREF will load the target page, stopping further processing of this script. Perhaps you can form an array in the loop and do a single POST with the array in body once loop exits?

Comment: It looks like your `i` variable is a global variable. You might want to add `var` in front of it.

Comment: @Exlord - The window.location.href is the only way I know how to send the variables to a PLSQL procedure to update

Comment: @Vasan -  I would love to use an array and pass each array of id's to the PLSQL procedure through an array but I am at a loss as to how to collect all the id's into an array.

Comment: @ErikToups how about ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. I am using an AJAX GET request within the loop with request params, so as to not change the interface as much as possible. It uses only plain JS since I am not sure if you have jquery.

The actual changes start from line 48. Of course, I could test this code only in a limited way, so it might have possible bugs (please let me know). Also this can be possibly refined further, but as a quick fix it should do.

**A word of caution:** This could make a lot of calls in quick succession. So if you have too many loop iterations you might end up bringing down the server. Use wisely! :-) There should be some kind of batching to avoid this, but that will need the call interface to be changed.

Lines 48-61: I am creating a plain JS object out of all your parameters. The key is parameter name, value is the value to be passed.

Line 63: Here I am defining a self-invoking function, which makes the AJAX call in its body. This way, even though AJAX is asynchronous in nature, it will run in sync with the for loop outside.

Line 64-66: I am serializing the object created in the loop, into query parameters.

Lines 68,69: Framing the URL to which request will be made.

Lines 71-77: Actually making the request. This is just boilerplate AJAX-invoking code you can find anywhere (jQuery would've made life so much simpler :-)).

```
function process_update(){

  var nDataCount = document.getElementById("v_nDataCount").value;
  var p_cc_no = document.getElementById("p_cc_no").value;
  var p_orient = document.getElementById("p_orient").value;
  var p_ot = document.getElementById("p_ot").value;
  var p_buy = document.getElementById("p_buy").value;
  var x = 0;


  if (nDataCount == 0) {
    x = 0;
  } else {
    x = 1;
  }

  for (i = nDataCount; i >= x; i--) {
    var p_pc_no = ("p_pc_no[" + i + "]");
    var p_pc_no2 = document.getElementById(p_pc_no).value;

    var p_tm_name = ("p_tm_name[" + i + "]");
    var p_tm_name2 = document.getElementById(p_tm_name).value;

    var p_tm_no = ("p_tm_no[" + i + "]");
    var p_tm_no2 = document.getElementById("p_tm_no").value;

    var p_status = ("p_status[" + i + "]");
    var p_status2 = document.getElementById(p_status).value;

    var p_hrs_per_week = ("p_hrs_per_week[" + i + "]");
    var p_hrs_per_week2 = document.getElementById(p_hrs_per_week).value;

    var p_shift = ("p_shift[" + i + "]");
    var p_shift2 = document.getElementById(p_shift).value;

    var p_open = ("p_open[" + i + "]");
    var p_open2 = document.getElementById(p_open).value;

    var p_vacant = ("p_vacant[" + i + "]");
    var p_vacant2 = document.getElementById(p_vacant).value;

    var p_comments = ("p_comments[" + i + "]");
    var p_comments2 = document.getElementById(p_comments).value;

    var p_delete = ("p_delete[" + i + "]");
    var p_delete2 = document.getElementById(p_delete).value;

    var dataObj = {p_cc_no:p_cc_no,
            p_pc_no:p_pc_no2,
            p_tm_name:p_tm_name2,
            p_tm_no:p_tm_no2,
            p_status:p_status2,
            p_hrs_per_week:p_hrs_per_week2,
            p_shift:p_shift2,
            p_open:p_open2,
            p_vacant:p_vacant2,
            p_comments:p_comments2,
            p_delete:p_delete2,
            p_orient:p_orient,
            p_ot:p_ot,
            p_buy:p_buy};

    (function(paramsObj){
        var paramsStr = Object.keys(paramsObj).map(function(key) {
            return key + '=' + paramsObj[key];
        }).join('&');

        var url = "https://server.server.com/db/schema.package.p_process2?";
        url += paramsStr;

        var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) {/*Handle Call Success*/};
        };
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.send();

    })(dataObj);
    }

}
```